# How to use function "getAttribute" to extract byte array from img with exif in Android?

Tags: java, android, exif

I am a newbie in JAVA programing.

And I want to use android.media.ExifInterface to save and restore some byte Array as exif information.

```
  String str = new String(byteArray);//save
  exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKER_NOTE, str);
  exif.saveAttributes();

  String str =exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKER_NOTE);//restore
  if(str != null)
  {
    byte[] byteArray = str.getBytes(); 
  }
```

Firstly I use `String(byte[])` to convert `byte[]` to String.
Then I use the function `setAttribute(String tag, String value)` to save the String with the tag TAG_MAKER_NOTE.
And when I want to extract the byteArray,I would use `getAttribute(String tag)` to get the corresponding string.

But I find the function `getAttribute(String tag)` can't work correctly if the saved byte array is as below:

```
 byte[] byteArray = new byte[]{ 1,2,3,4,0,0,5,6};
```

The returned string only contains `{1,2,3,4}`. It lose the data after 0 .The length of string is 4 while the saved string is normal. Maybe the string regards 0 as the end ?

And I want to know is there any solution to extract the whole byte array ? Whithout 3rd library is better.

Comment: The issue seems to be like tdelev says. It's related to `String` conversion rather than saving and storing. Java uses Unicode, and a character `0` is a `null` character (which usually is used for the end of a string). Are you trying to store and retrieve a list of numbers?

Comment: Yes, I want to store and retrieve a list of binary data just like memcpy in cpp. But the string before I saved is different with which I restored from the exif

Comment: you'll have to figure out a way to encode the binary data as a string that can be decoded back intact. The `String` constructor that takes a `byte[]` parameter won't work for you, since there are some value combinations that yield invalid text. Base64 like tdelev suggests is one way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `new String(byteArray)` to convert to String, use a base64 encoded string. The code would look like this:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 5, 6};
String str = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArray);
System.out.println(str);
byte[] result = Base64.getDecoder().decode(str);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```